# Creating Real Time Database with SignalR in Asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am student developer in Asp .Net platform. According to my research , real time database is possible using Asp.Net. That's why I know I need to use SignalR. In fallowing my example I tried to build it but I am facing null value while fetching my data from SQL Server. I am not professional and I do not know what is the problem or where problem comes. Many source are not clear for student can understand in build real time database issue. Could you help me at this issue ? Maybe your answers might be an example to students like me. Thanks.

My model:

```
public partial class TextMessage
    {        
        public int textId { get; set; }
        public string textOwner { get; set; }
        public string textContent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> groupFk { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> textDate { get; set; }   
        public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My script part in my Layout Page:

```
 <script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var text = $.connection.AgmHub;
            text.client.displayTextMessage = function () {
                getData();
            };
            $.connection.hub.start();
            getData;
        });
    function getData() {
            var $tbl = $('#tblInfo');
            $.ajax({
                url: $("#Get").val(),
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $.each(data.listEmp, function (i, model) {
                        $tbl.append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + textId + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + textOwner + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + textContent + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + groupFk + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + textDate + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
                            );
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

My controller and my method :

```
 public JsonResult Get()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgmEntities1"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"Select [Id],[textId],[textOwner],[textContent],[groupFk],[textDate] From [dbo].[TextMessage] where [Status]<> 0", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    var listText = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new
                    {
                        Id = (int)x["Id"],
                        textOwner = (string)x["textOwner"],
                        textContent = (string)x["textContent"],
                        groupFk = (int)x["groupFk"],
                        textDate = (System.DateTime)x["textDate"],
                    }).ToList();
                    return Json(new { listText = listText }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            AgmHub.Show();
        }
```

My Index.cshtml :

```
@Html.Hidden("Get", Url.Action("Get", "TextMessage"))
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                area1:
            </th>
            <th>
               area2:
            </th>
            <th>
                area3:
            </th>
            <th>
              area4:
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblInfo">

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: By "real time database" do you mean display database changes on a web page in real time using SignalR? What line of code is giving you the null reference exception?

Comment: Yes. I mean display on my html page  at same time with SQL  while insert , update or delete.

Comment: When you debug, what line of code is giving you the null reference exception?

Comment: My code is working correctly. I am not facing an any null error. just my screen is empty except area1 , area2 ,area3,area4.

Comment: Maybe my Get function might has a problem. I dont know.

Comment: Does your database query return all the rows you are expecting? I am trying to determine if it is a back-end or front-end issue.

Comment: I tried it with break point my listText variable is null. So in back end might has 
a problem.

Comment: listText has an error like this `An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Agm.dll but was not handled in user code` @mr.coffee

Comment: One of your database casts is probably failing. Try using int.TryParse and DateTime.TryParse when reading the database rows.

Comment: it is not working. TryParse and int.TryParse give an error.